# Caddy HDD cannot be mounted after restart

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs

I have two laptops. The previous one (HP G42, 2011) had Windows 8 + Ubuntu 16.04. A fewer driver. Probably two of them

The new one (HP Probook 450 G4) has 240 GB SSD + 1TB of HDD replacing my CD Drive. 
Which runs Ubuntu 18.04. 

While I was copying my previous files to the new laptop via rsync. my new laptop charge went down to zero. then when I rebooted my laptop, I find that it's not mounting anymore.

`sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb1`: command says

```
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018) 
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block 
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks... 
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1 

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 
filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock 
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock: 
e2fsck -b 8193 <device> 
or 
e2fsck -b 32768 <device> 

/dev/sdb1 contains a ntfs file system labelled 'Files'
```

`sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb` says

```
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018) 
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block 
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks... 
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb 

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 
filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock 
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock: 
e2fsck -b 8193 <device> 
or 
e2fsck -b 32768 <device> 

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb
```

Can anyone please help me out? Not an expert on Ubuntu/Linux. Is there any way to recover it w/o formatting the whole drive? Had some backup of my other files in my new Laptop.

Edit: I was not copying OS related files. I was copying my own documents.

Comment: images: (Disks: https://imgur.com/qlfFGF0)  (e2fsck/sdb: https://imgur.com/BpAsQLo) (e2fsck/sdb2: https://imgur.com/siUD5IJ)

Comment: Since the filesystem is ntfs, you could try to run a check on Windows. Also, I'd be careful with the -f flag. Forcing an fsck check on an unknown filesystem might cause data corruption.

Comment: @mikewhatever, I don't want to install windows on my current laptop. Unless I have an option, I have to do that. Is there any other way available to do so?

Comment: You don't have to install Windows, just use another PC with Windows. Simple!

Comment: Should I have to detach my caddy HDD? Then I can't do that. Any tutorial? Sorry for being dumb.

Comment: Well, there something called `ntfsfix` in Ubuntu, but it is not a "Linux version of chkdsk". Read `man ntfsfix`, and then, if you don't mind risking data loss, use it. Good luck.

Comment: Luck is what he'll need @mikewhatever Better ask a friend to run `CHKDSK /F`

Comment: Yes, I will go to service center and tell them to run that command. Can't uncover the back cover and Don't have that gut :(

Comment: @mikewhatever @Fabby yes. did the `chkdsk` operation. and It's okay now. Thanks both of you guys. Will add the answer when I am on  my PC.

Comment: Please don’t forget to add an answer.